# NY lottery feed

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to find a feed either in XML or Json so I can use to display results of NY lottery and next drawing dates on my website. I was going to use jquery to display the results. Anyone know of any feeds I could use that are easy to extract the data from.  I just need NY lottery mega millions and power ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this on a previous project - http://www.lotteryxml.com/. Worked quite well  for me and I think it now includes the next drawing dates.

Answer (score 0):

You could just screen scrape the lottery web page. You could use beutiful soup.